# How to write/format a digression in conference/thesis papers

Tags: publications, thesis

I am currently writing a paper and in one of the sections it would be appropriate to write a quick digression to explain one topic in more detail. 
My structure would be something like

```
Section X (H1)
  [some normal text]

  Digression: Bla in detail (H2)
  [text of digression]

  [continue with text from Section X]
```

But that way, there is no clear part for the reader to see that the digression is over.

So how do I structurally return from a digression to continue with the initial topic? How are digressions usually structured and set apart from the rest of the section in conference/thesis papers?

*(Is it even good practice to have digressions?)*

Comment: I think this depends on the field and on the extent of the digression. What's the purpose of the digression anyway? Also, if it's one paragraph long, just start the next paragraph with sth like "_regarding the topic previously discussed/the main topic of this work/etc._".

Comment: Indeed, the extent of the digression matters. Sometimes a footnote is the best way - certainly the least intrusive one.

Comment: The digression is about programming language details and roughly one paragraph, so - in my opinion - too long for a footnote.

Comment: Normally papers do not have chapters, they have sections.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I meant to say sections (got lost in translation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can format it as a [**remark**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216005/in-a-math-paper-what-is-a-remark). These are essentially paragraphs typeset with a special header, a bit like theorems. Example from a paper in my field:

[image]

Note that the text of the paragraph is typeset in a roman typeface, not in italic like a theorem. If you are using Latex, with `amsmath`, there is a command `\theoremstyle{remark}` that can be used to get theorem-like environments with that formatting.